# RailsアプリをCapistrano+Unicorn+Nginxでデプロイするも、サイトにアクセスできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

みなさん、お世話になります。

[(初心者向け）vpsを契約して、capistrano3でRailsアプリをデプロイするまで [その1 サーバー設定編]](https://qiita.com/ryo2132/items/f62690f0b16ec11270fe)
上記を参考にRailsアプリをConohaにデプロイするところまで完了しました。
最後にアクセス確認しようとしたところ、以下のエラーが表示されてしまいました。

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

VPSにアクセスし、nginx.error.logを確認したところ、以下のエラーが発生していました。

```
2019/10/xx xx:xx:xx [crit] 17197#0: *18 connect() to unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: x.x.x.x, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock:/", host: "x.x.x.x"
```

`/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock`は存在しませんでした。

このファイルはUnicornとNginxが通信するために必要なファイルだという認識です。
このファイルが存在しないということは、Unicornの設定がおかしいのかと思い何度も見直したんですが、おかしなところはなさそうに思えます。

`config/unicorn/production.rb`内で以下のように`listen`しています。

```
  $listen  = '/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock'
  ...
  listen  $listen
```

unicorn.sockが作られるべきタイミングはここでしょうか？
なぜunicorn.sockが作られていないのかご存じの方はいますでしょうか？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/216119

Answer (score 0):

> unicorn.sockが作られるべきタイミング

は、`bundle exec cap production deploy`したときに、unicornが起動して、unicorn.sockが作成されるはずです。

おそらく、自分がデプロイしたディレクトリのlog/unicorn.logに何らかのエラーが出て、unicornが起動していない可能性が考えられます。まずは、unicorn.logと、unicornが起動してるかをpsコマンドで確認することからだと思います。

なお、もし、unicorn.logに何も出てないのであれば、unicorn起動以前のcapistrano内部で何か失敗しているかもしれません。

Comment: 実はデプロイ中にエラーが発生していました。そのエラーは`config/deploy.rb`内で行っているunicornの再起動（restart）のところを、unicornの起動（start）に変更することで対処していました。この対処がunicorn.sockが作成されていない原因ではないかと思い、unicornの再起動（restart）に戻してデプロイからやり直しています。しかし、そこでもエラーが発生するので、別途質問をあげさせてもらいました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59584/capistrano%e3%81%a7rails%e3%82%a2%e3%83%97%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e3%83%87%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%a4%e4%b8%ad%e3%81%abunicorn%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a6%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f-railsunicornnginx